# Which template name to use for taxonomies but not their terms?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, template-hierarchy

I can't figure out which template name to use to modify custom taxonomy archive page, but not the one for terms in that taxonomy.

My goal is to show terms list in custom taxonomy archive and in custom taxonomy terms - custom post types..

`{taxonomy}-{term}.php` is used to display custom taxonomy terms ( so there will be custom post types inside ) but i need so there would be terms list inside.

Hope my question in clear.

### Edit:

Just found out that I can't open that kind of page in wordpress at all..
So now question is how to make such page?

For ex. I have ct - `device`. So `/device/iphone` will show all posts in `iphone` term,
but `/device/` should show all terms in device tax.

My problem is that `/device/` is readed as page slug, not tax in wordpress by default.

How to change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such hierarchy in Wordpress, accessing a custom taxonomy directly simply `404`. This works for all taxonomies, build-in or not. There is unfortuantely no other work around to this but to create a page

You should create a custom page template with a custom query to list your taxonomy terms, something like the following

- Create a page template called `page-device.php`
- Use [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to create your list, something like this: (*Extend as needed, taken from the `get_terms()` page*)

  ```
  $terms = get_terms( 'device' );
  if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
      echo '<ul>';
          foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
              echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
          }
      echo '</ul>';
  }
  ```
- Create a page in the back-end with slug `device`

Now, if you visit `mysite.com/device/`, you will see this page showing up with all your terms in the taxonomy `device`